# How to do custom checking before the REST API called in Spring?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

I have a problem where the user **still can call the API after logout the application** by using **POSTMAN**. There is no problem with the browser side after logged out since I have removed the access token and clear the cookies. But the user still can call the API and get the results using POSTMAN, which means the back-end doesn't invalidate the OAuth token. This may cause **security issues** if anyone stole the access code.

I have think to apply validation before the API called. I will add a column in the database table which its' value is either **login** or **logout** to indicate the current user status. Then, I will fetch this value from database for every API called to do validation. If the value is logout, then the API will return some error message. Is it possible to do by using the spring security?

Comment: Is this about a specific spring component? If so, please indicate name & version.